# type guards: typescript inferring never but it shouldn't

Tags: typescript

The issue is pretty straightforward, related to type guards:

```
abstract class A {

    abstract isB(): this is B;
    abstract isC(): this is C;
    abstract get(): number;
}

class B extends A {

    isB(): this is B {
        return true;
    }

    isC(): this is C {
        return false;
    }

    get() {
        return 5;
    }
}

class C extends A {

    isB(): this is B {
        return false;
    }

    isC(): this is C {
        return true;
    }

    get() {
        return 6;
    }
}

const x = new C();
if (x.isB()) {
    console.log("B!")
} else {
    console.log(x.get()); <--- x is inferred to never
}
```

As you can see, at the next-to-last line, `x` is inferred to `never` while it's quite obviously `C`. I'm pretty sure it's [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10934) that I've hit, and I even I think understand what's the issue "Because Single is assignable to Empty, the code flow analysis is eliminating both of them from the union type".

However I don't understand how to take advantage of the workaround which is suggested.

I did check that the issue does not appear if I don't have `A` as a base class, but rather define `B` and `C` independently and then say `type A = B | C`. In that case typescript is even inferring the type to be `C` in the `else` block. I guess it's impossible to achieve such a nice type inference with inheritance, the way I have it set up currently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right about the issue; your `B` and `C` are structurally identical, and therefore TypeScript (up to and including v2.6) decides that if you have eliminated the possibility that `x` is `B`, then you have also eliminated the possibility that `x` is `C`.  This is one of the features of a structural type system; if you want the compiler to distinguish two types, they should be distinguishable *structurally* (have some different members), not just *nominally* (have different names).

The easiest way to work around this is to add some distinguishing property to the definition of `B` or `C` or both.  It doesn't even have to exist at runtime;  it just has to convince the compiler that `B` and `C` are different.  Here's one possibility:

```
class B extends A {

    readonly className: "B"  // add this line

    // ... no change

}

class C extends A {

    readonly className: "C"  // add this line

    // ... no change

}
```

Now `B` and `C` have a `className` property of different string literal types. (Only at compile time; nothing extra is emitted to JavaScript).  Confirm that the problem goes away:

```
const x = new C();
if (x.isB()) {
    console.log("B!")
} else {
    console.log(x.get()); //<--- x is C
}
```

So, you can do that.  Now, in TypeScript v2.7, which hasn't been released yet as of 2017-Dec-15, there will be a [change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/19671) that prevents the compiler from collapsing structually-identical-but-nominally-different types in certain circumstances.  I'm not sure if your above code would suddenly start working without the extra properties, but it's a possibility.  So check back soon, I guess.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you, that helps. typescript@2.7.0-dev.20171216 still needs the explicit difference. I have a followup question though, but maybe I should open a new question.. With the sample code I pasted, everything works great with your changes, x is `C` in the else branch. However in my real code I build x through a static method in `A`:    `static make(input: boolean):A {  return  input ? new B() : new C(); }` -- with that `x` is not inferred to `C` in the `else` but to `A` :-( any idea how to fix that? new sample => https://gist.github.com/emmanueltouzery/bfd684fea04c942b46f5a538ececf22c

Comment: yeah already in the first line having `const x = <A>new C();` has `x` inferred to `A` in the else. This is what I mentioned in my question: "define B and C independently and then say `type A = B | C`. In that case typescript is even inferring the type to be C in the else block". I think the problem is that inheritance is "open", there could be a new subclass of `A`. With `type A = B | C` there can only be `C`. So I think in reality inheritance here offers strictly less than independent types & an or type.

Comment: Oh, sure.  If you use inheritance, then `A` isn't exhaustively `B` or `C`; just as `string` isn't exclusively `"foo"` or `"bar"`, even if you only use `"foo"` or `"bar"` in your code.  If you want `B | C` you should just use `B | C`.  This doesn't mean you can't keep `A` as a superclass; it just means that you should declare that `make()` returns `B | C` instead of `A`.  Up to you.

Comment: great, thank you, that helps again! I didn't cross my mind to keep the inheritance hierarchy _but_ return `B | C`...

Comment: btw about inheritance one could think that at compile-time the compiler could still find out that there aren't any other subclasses in the app.. but i guess it's not that simple.

Comment: note that this code doesn't build with typescript 2.7rc anymore. I've changed it to `readonly className: "B" = <any>undefined;`.